# Nginx not listening at local address

Tags: nginx

I have a host nginx in WSL running on Docker. I can't access from other devices in same local network.

When I go to localhost on my pc, I can connect, but when I go to my router's public ip on the host pc (like 192.168.xxx.xxx) or 127.0.0.1, I got 400(Bad request). Help me...

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    error_log    /logs/nginx.error.log error;
    access_log   /logs/nginx.access.log;
    client_max_body_size 48M;

    add_header X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    charset utf-8;
    try_files $uri @icons;
    error_page 502 504 /502.html;

    location ~ ^/502\.html$|^/logo\.png$|^/robots\.txt$ {
        root /assets/;
    }

    location @icons {
        root /assets/resources/icons/;
        log_not_found off;
        error_page 403 = @uwsgi;
        error_page 404 = @uwsgi;
    }

    location @uwsgi {
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
        uwsgi_pass site:8000;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx/$nginx_version;
    }


    location /event/ {
        proxy_pass http://wsevent:15100;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }

    location /channels/ {
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_pass http://wsevent:15102;
    }
}
```

And here is part of nginx in `docker-compose`

```yaml
nginx:
    container_name: vnoj_nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - assets:/assets/
      - pdfcache:/pdfcache/
      - userdatacache:/userdatacache/
      - contestdatacache:/contestdatacache/
      - cache:/cache/
      - ./logs/:/logs/
      - ./media/:/media/
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks: [ nginx ]
```

Comment: What's your docker command to run nginx?

Comment: I only config and run it with docker-compose, have no command when start

Comment: show your docker compose code

Comment: I post it in here: https://pastebin.com/uyhHLuRR